# How to store coordinates(Latitude,Longitude) in RDF

Tags: c#, coordinates, rdf, protege, rdfs

I have a c# class showing the coordinates as

```
 class Coordinates{
   double lat;
   double lon;
 }
```

how can i convert it in rdf triples in rdf as the RDF does not support double type?and if float is used i can only represent 6 digits after the "." any idea?

I am using [Protege 3.4.8](http://protege.stanford.edu/) to create my rdf schema and [Semweb](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/) to write triples of data in the scema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by manually changing the RDF file produced by Protege and putting http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double at the point i needed it.

Comment: yes but there is something wrong and it cannot start at all not only at my system but also at another that i tried...

Answer (score 1):

RDF [does support floating-point literals](http://rdf.rubyforge.org/RDF/Literal/Double.html). And *Semweb* supports [`Literal` values](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/semweb-current/apidocs/SemWeb/Literal.html) too.

Use the [`FromValue` method](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/semweb-current/apidocs/SemWeb/Literal.html#M%3aSemWeb.Literal.FromValue%28System.Double%29) to get it to do what you want it to do.

Comment: ok i mean Protege 3.4.8 does not support double value to be inserted for my schema..